# Need help text of more than 255 characters

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I need to use **helptext** with one custom field in Visualforce but Salesforce it allows 255 characters in helptext with a field. One solution is to create an image of text and show that image onMouseOver. Can you suggest me other solutions?

Comment: Why don't you create a new "Text Area" field with up to 32.768  characters?

Comment: @mast0r, it looks like Pankaj needs >255 characters for the hover-help-text, not the input field.

Comment: yes sumanKrishnasha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`, it has a helptext attribute that corresponds to the balloon. You can put your "long help" in a custom label for example so it can be translated to other languages like standard help texts.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Lorem ipsum ... (400+ chars)">
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.CurrencyIsoCode.Label}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

[image: Sample screenshot of long "Lorem ipsum" in a help tip.]

Comment: is this support hyperlink inside Help Text?

Answer (score 1):

If you are competent in JavaScript and using JavaScript libraries, 
use `<apex:inputText title="LongHelpTextGoesHere" />`
in your Visualforce page with either of the following:

1. http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html
2. http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: I'd say that's a huge overkill to use jQuery for something so simple. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif ? ;)

Comment: @eyescream, funny screenshot in your comment! Agree with your answer to the question. I was not aware of the helpText attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring'21 Salesforce release,

[Get More Characters for Field-Level Help Text](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_fields_characters.htm&type=5&release=230)

Customers can view the field-level help text by hovering over the Info icon. And with the character limit expanded from 255 to 510, you can now provide more detailed help information. This increase applies to standard and custom fields on detail and edit pages.

**Where:**

This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.