# need an alternative for the help text field limitation

Tags: custom, button, helptext

When creating a new record, I need to be able to show a popup with some text.
I tried using the help text on my custom fields but the field is too limited in size.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail? Quite confusing.

Comment: The first line of the Salesforce document 'Custom Button Considerations' states "Custom buttons display at the top and bottom of the detail page to the right of all standard buttons." I need a custom button or something that offers similar functionality to execute Javascript or Visualforce, on the 'New' page, not the detail page for a record. The result I need is a very basic text message box to pop up. However, clearly this is not support with custom buttons.

Comment: Will you use Visualforce page for inserts or standard ones? If VF - you could check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/need-help-text-of-more-than-255-characters out.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a managed package that gives me limited ability to make changes. That is why a custom button would be perfect. Thanks for your suggestions, tho.

Answer (score 1):

How I understand this question:
You want to be able to show some popup with text providing an explanation about the field or something on the page. You tried using the help text on a field but got stuck on the help text field limitation. (size etc)

What could be a solution for you is to use the context-sensitive help setting of your custom object. This is the page that you see when clicking on the "Help for this Page" for that specific object.
You also get this link when you are in the form to create a new record of your custom object.

[image]

You can create such a custom contextual help page by creating a new Visualforce Page.
You don't need any code for it though, the visualforce page can just be plain an simple HTML / formatting.

You can set this visualforce page as the contextual help by going to your custom object (create > object menu), editing the custom object setting and there you will have a field "Context-Sensitive Help Setting". Point that field to your newly created visualforce page.

Comment: Yes, I considered the object help which can be coded in visualforce but it is on the whole object and not specific to the field. I guess there is no really good workaround. Wonder why is the custom button limited to the 'details' page only ? Also why is help so small ? These both seem like easily addressable design limitations of the Salesforce UI. Have these been submitted as ideas for future enhancements

Comment: There already exists an idea for this on the ideas exchange.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpE1AAK 
I did hit that limit too one time. On the other hand, it is my feeling that one field should probably never be that complex that it would require that much explanation. When you want to stick to the standard salesforce functionality / page layouts, I guess the help for this page is still your best bet.